# SpringJMS 3.0.4 not connecting MQ 7.5 Connection using UserName

Tags: authentication, mq, spring-jms

SpringJMS 3.0.4 not connecting MQ 7.5 Connection using UserName

Not able to connect MQ 7.5 Queue manager from Spring JMS version 3.0.4 with username. Username is passed to provide appropriate authorization to queue. We are using SpringJMS which uses MQ Client libraries available on the same machine. MQ Manager/Server is on remote machine

Below is the configuration we are using but we are getting error message as shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd         http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd">

<!-- :: Messaging Infrastructure Beans :: -->

<bean id="transport" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.FieldRetrievingFactoryBean" p:staticField="com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP" />

  <bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory" p:transportType-ref="transport"
  p:queueManager="${tcs.messaging.queueManager.name}" p:hostName="${tcs.messaging.queueManager.host}" p:port="${tcs.messaging.queueManager.port}"
  p:channel="${tcs.messaging.queueManager.channel}" />

<bean id="queueConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory"
  p:targetConnectionFactory-ref="mqConnectionFactory" p:sessionCacheSize="${tcs.messaging.connectionFactory.sessionCacheSize}"
  p:exceptionListener-ref="providerMessageListener" />

<bean id="providerMessageListener" class="com.uhg.treasury.customerservice.management.transport.jms.ProviderExceptionListener" />

<!-- New Addition ::   -->
   <bean id="myConnectionFactory2" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
      <property name="targetConnectionFactory"> <ref bean ="mqConnectionFactory"/> </property>
     <property name="username"> <value>"tbossmqd"</value> </property>
     <property name="password"> <value>"password1"</value> </property>
  </bean>

</beans>
```

**Error Message is as below**

2014-06-27 11:25:42,503 [main] DEBUG - DefaultMessageListenerContainer.establishSharedConnection(752) | Could not establish shared JMS Connection - leaving it up to asynchronous invokers to establish a Connection as soon as possible
com.ibm.msg.client.jms.DetailedJMSSecurityException: JMSWMQ2013: The security authentication was not valid that was supplied for QueueManager 'WMQT013' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'wmqlt0006.xxx.com(1960)'.
Please check if the supplied username and password are correct on the QueueManager to which you are connecting.
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.reasonToException(Reason.java:521)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:221)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQConnection.(WMQConnection.java:426)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createV7ProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6902)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.factories.WMQConnectionFactory.createProviderConnection(WMQConnectionFactory.java:6277)
    at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.admin.JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.createConnection(JmsConnectionFactoryImpl.java:285)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory.createCommonConnection(MQConnectionFactory.java:6233)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createQueueConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:120)
    at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.createConnection(MQQueueConnectionFactory.java:203)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.doCreateConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.initConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createConnection(SingleConnectionFactory.java:225)
    at org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createConnection(JmsAccessor.java:184)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.createSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:403)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.establishSharedConnection(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:371)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.establishSharedConnection(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:749)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.doStart(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:278)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.start(AbstractJmsListeningContainer.java:263)
    at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer.start(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:555)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:166)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$1(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:154)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:335)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:158)
    at com.uhg.treasury.customerservice.management.Server.(Server.java:61)
    at com.uhg.treasury.customerservice.management.Server.(Server.java:43)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.MQException: JMSCMQ0001: WebSphere MQ call failed with compcode '2' ('MQCC_FAILED') reason '2035' ('MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED').
    at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.Reason.createException(Reason.java:209)
    ... 29 more
2014-06-27 11:25:42,512 [main] DEBUG - AbstractJmsListeningContainer.resumePausedTasks(539) | Resumed paused task: org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker@627a94a9
2014-06-27 11:25:42,512 [main] DEBUG - AbstractJmsListeningContainer.resumePausedTasks(539) | Resumed paused task: org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker@5db615c1

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that the `MQQueueuConnectionFactory.createConnection` method been called by Spring is the version that passes no username/password. This is why you are seeing the MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED as the username is not being passed to the queue manager.

I am not a spring expert but I believe that the new myConnectionFactory2 bean that you have added needs to reference your CachingConnectionFactory bean (queueConnectionFactory) rather than directly referencing the MQQueueConnectionFactory bean (mqConnectionFactory). So change this:

```
<bean id="myConnectionFactory2" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
      <property name="targetConnectionFactory"> <ref bean ="mqConnectionFactory"/> </property>
     <property name="username"> <value>"tbossmqd"</value> </property>
     <property name="password"> <value>"password1"</value> </property>
  </bean>
```

to be this:

```
<bean id="myConnectionFactory2" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.UserCredentialsConnectionFactoryAdapter">
      <property name="targetConnectionFactory"> <ref bean ="queueConnectionFactory"/> </property>
     <property name="username"> <value>"tbossmqd"</value> </property>
     <property name="password"> <value>"password1"</value> </property>
  </bean>
```